# Access H2 Database from Outside of the App

Tags: database-administration, h2

I have an embedded H2 database running for a web-app that I am working on.  The programmer who built the app has gone and I am faced with learning the system and figuring out a way to look into this database.  So what I'm looking for is something like HeidiSQL or SQuirreL SQL Client, or the MySQL console, whereby I can login, query the database, make changes, etc...

Since this is an embedded database, the H2 website (and PDF) docs are sparse.  I spent some time reading up on the H2 website, and so far, all I have found is a paragraph on how to actually use H2 embedded database, like the Java driver class, the H2 JAR, the URL, etc...

Does anyone know how I can access this database?  The application is a server-client app running on my local machine.  The directory structure that has database info in it looks like this:

[image]

Otherwise I have no idea where I would even find the database itself or any related files.  The H2 website talks about a test.h2.db file but I don't have one.  Any help is much appreciated.

UPDATE: I made some headway, but I still cannot connect.  I'm using SQuirreL SQL with the H2 driver, org.h2.Driver class.  The config seems to be correct, but the URL I'm using is not right for connection.  Basically I'm using the directory below as the URL with "test" appended:

```
C:\Users\<user>\<app_name>\db\test
```

And I've tried each file name in the directory above as the URL as well, with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install Razor SQL, and use org.hs.Driver.  Much easier than mucking with Squirrel ;)